# NS2: How to simulate nodes running two different mac protocols in a single network?

Tags: macos, protocols, ns2, hybrid, mesh-network

I want to modify the existing routing protocol and simulate how well does it work on a network with two different types of nodes, cars with 802.11p and AP on the roadside with 802.3.

Does anyone know how to run a routing protocol simulation on a network with two different mac protocols, such as 802.11p combined with 802.3 ??? Any links I'll be appreciated.